# Read MPU6050 accelerometer data directly using Android

Tags: android, accelerometer, i2c, mpu6050

I have a custom hardware that runs on Android 8.1. The hardware has an MPU6050 accelerometer sensor.

Can I directly read the MPU6050 data through Android application? Or would I need a [C program like this](https://gist.github.com/JGrossholtz/24e427b62c2e5dbbec6546c55c8979d8#gistcomment-4315924) to read the actual data and then identify a way to read that through my Android application? i.e. Are there any Android libraries / APIs that I can use to read streaming sensor data.

If the sensor is already recognizible by Android, I can use [Android Sensor Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager). But in my case, the sensor is currently only recognizible through `i2c-detect`. So I am trying to understand how I can read I2C sensor data into my Android application.

Comment: The terminology used is confusing. Use Android NDK and JNI.

Comment: MPU6050 is a common accelerometer sensor. I have added more details. Hope this clarifies.